# Center Message box on Any Screen Resolution

Tags: css, styles, center

Please Help me to center the message box on fit on any screen resolution..
can you show what css or style, margins, left, right,that I can use?

Comment: It is not possible to vertically center content with arbitrary heights using just css.

Comment: I think your only option is going to be javascript. You will need to re position the box if the screen size changes.

Comment: If you can fix the content height, it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just saw this after reading about how to do one on a [CSS Techniques](http://dhirajkumarsingh.wordpress.com/2013/12/01/css-techniques-absolute-horizontal-and-vertical-centering-in-css/) page.

Basically, define a little CSS:

```
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

### ADVANTAGES:

- Cross-browser (including IE8-10)
- No special markup, minimal styles
- Responsive with percentages and min-/max-
- Use one class to center any content

I have not had time to test it out, but I wanted to post it up here in the hope that it helps others.

Answer (score 9):

## Center Horizontally

To center a div horizontally you can use `margin: auto auto; width: 500px` where the width is any width you want it to be.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andho/bD9vu/)

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    Some content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto auto;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

## Center screen with fixed dimensions

If you can fix the content height and width then it's possible to center the div both horizontally and vertically using just css. This is achieved by wrapping your content in another div, then positioning your content div's `top: 50%` and then subtracting half the height of it's margin from it: `margin-top: -100px`, assuming the height was 200px. See example below:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andho/6gwPT/).

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        Some content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #EEE;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    background-color: #DDD;
}
```

## Pretend it's vertically centered

Also you can give a fixed `margin-top` (or `top` with `position: absolute`) to make it seem vertically centered in most desktop and laptop screens.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andho/3RfBa/)

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    Some content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

## Use Javascript

It is not possible to vertically center content with arbitrary height using just css. In this case you will need to use Javascript to position the div.:

The basic idea is:

- you calculate the height of the content at the time you need to show the content, or when the content is loaded.
- Then change any of the many css properties to position the div at the vertical center.

My personal preference is you to use `position: absolute` with `top` property. You can also use `margin-top` but you probably don't want this div to take up space in the box model if you have other content on the page.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andho/bD9vu/)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var el = $('#content');
    var elWidth = el.width();
    var elHeight = el.height();

    el.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: (windowHeight / 2) - (elHeight / 2),
        left: (windowWidth / 2) - (elWidth / 2),
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    Some content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Use any of the many Javascript "plugins" available

There is a multitude of CSS frameworks around the web that provide boilerplate CSS that we use on most websites. And some of these also help with these kind of common presentation issues with small Javascript plugins. Personally I know that [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) provides a [Modal plugin](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) which you can use for this purpose. There is also many jQuery plugins for the sole purpose of centering content in a page.

## Conclusion

Although there is a multitude of options to achieve this, I it sad to see that CSS still does not support doing this. Maybe it's a hard thing to do across different scenarios, I don't know. From the options that I mention above, I think the Javascript option is the most versatile, and with todays browser speeds, and the likeliness that nobody would have Javascript disabled on their browser, this would be the best way to go.

Comment: You forgot the `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle` method.

Comment: Stupid how you can have gradients and shadows and rounded corners (all which are "fashionable"), but can't do something simple/core like vertical alignment.

Comment: Thanks guys u guys helped me a lot. Keep it up

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are searching for http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/centering-div-vertically-and-horizontally/

You can easily make it with jquery! Or with an css solution given on this site!

Answer (score 0):

You should give us your code that you have tried. Assume that you have HTML code like below:

```
<div id="message">
   Hello World!
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#message {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   margin: 50px auto;
}
```

Then your message box will be 100x100 and 50px from the top of the screen and automatically aligns to the center of the screen.